# Disk Managment reporting two different sizes of same partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, disk-space

I am migrating a win 10 install from a 250GB drive to a 1.5TB drive.

I used clonezilla to clone the drive and scale the windows partition up to fill the unused space.

Upon booting back into windows something strange is happening, disk management shows 2 separate values for the size of the same partition:

[image: Screenshot]

Windows explorer still shows the partition as 250GB

I want to shrink the partition down to approx 200GB and create a separate media partition of about 1.2TB

Using the shrink tool in Disk Management - i see that the max i can shrink the partition by is ~80GB - The same as the unused space that is reported in explorer and DM. I know there to be about 1.3TB of unused space in the partition.

Anyone know why DM is displaying the partition size incorrectly ?

If anyone could point me in the right direction to fix this I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some partition table somewhere was wrong. I had a hunch that if i deleted the recovery partition and extended the C: partition to fill the space that everything would report correctly.

It worked - extended the partition by the 2.5gb and all the figures aligned. I could then shrink by the 1.2TB